# Carriage Returns Breaking MySQL BulkLoader

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, csv

I'm importing Data from Visual FoxPro into MySQL and I'm having trouble reading a `Memo` column type. The issue is that in the Memo column in FoxPro users are able to enter carriage returns.

I load the FoxPro table into a CSV file, and the issue appears, the carriage returns are counted as new lines which messes the import process up when I'm using `MySqlBulkLoader`. The CSV file looks like this;

```
Contact1
Contact2
description associated with Contact2
description associated with Contact2
Contact3
```

The issue here is that there are carriage returns in the description of Contact2. Is there a way I can loop through the CSV file so that it can ignore carriage returns, but maintain them in the MySQL database? Could I even loop through the C# `DataTable` and remove them there? Therefore not being confused by taking the carriage returns but maintaining them in the `MySQL` side of things.

These are the methods I'm using at the moment;

```
    private void Contacts()     
    {
        using (OleDbConnection dbfCon = new OleDbConnection(dbfConstr))
        {
            dbfCon.Open();
            var dbfCmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT ct_id, ct_cmpid, ct_empid,
            ct_pplid, ct_cntid, ct_pplnm, ct_date, ct_time, ct_type, ct_doneby
            FROM contacts", dbfCon);
            var dTable = new DataTable();
            var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbfCmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            WriteDateTimeToCSV(dTable, "contacts");
        }
    }
```

**Load Data From CSV to MySQL**

```
    public void WriteDateTimeToCSV(DataTable dataTable, string mySqlTable)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

        Type _datetype = typeof(DateTime);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select((field, index) => (dataTable.Columns[index].DataType == _datetype) ? ((DateTime)field).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") :
            (field.ToString().Contains(",") ? "\"" + field.ToString() + "\"" : field.ToString()));
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));

        }
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\test.csv", sb.ToString());
        WriteToMySQL(mySqlTable);
    }
```

**WriteToMySQL**

```
    public void WriteToMySQL(string mySqlTable)
    {
        MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConstr);
        mysqlCon.Open();
        string tempCsvFileSpec = @"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\test.csv";
        var msbl = new MySqlBulkLoader(mysqlCon);
        msbl.TableName = "sdcdatabase." + mySqlTable;
        msbl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
        msbl.FileName = tempCsvFileSpec;
        msbl.FieldTerminator = ",";
        msbl.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
        msbl.Load();
        File.Delete(tempCsvFileSpec);
    }
```

EDIT: This is the CSV opened in Notepad++

```
32,2199,9,26,0,Dan                              ,1996-08-13,16:56:12  ,4,Dan    ,"OTT 30/08/96. CRLF
    Test 1 CRLF
    Test 2 CRLF
    Test 3 CRLF
    33,3146,9,512,0,Dan                          ,1996-08-20,10:51:14  ,1,Dan    ,Call again re Malvern CRLF
```

This is what I have tried so far to replace the CR;

```
        if (row[10].ToString().Contains("CR"))
        {
            row[10].ToString().Replace("CR", "!");
        }
```

But unfortunately the CR is not replaced

Comment: Replace CR with another symbol when convert to CSV, then replace it back after import to MySQL.

Comment: @Oleg How would I detect and replace CR in a DataRow? Also how would I detect it on the other end after using the MySQL BulkLoader?